# +[NSData bookmarkDataWithContentsOfURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: objective-c, macos, class, objective-c++, class-method

I am trying to resolve an alias file's original path using Objective-C(or maybe C++; it's an `.mm` file). Not being very much familiar, I am somehow missing `+` and `-` methods' usage. I am aware of them being class and instance methods respectively, but in practice, the following the code, with the indicated lines give me following warning and error(at build):

> Class method '+bookmarkDataWithContentsOfURL:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

-

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSData bookmarkDataWithContentsOfURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fff88942cb8'

with `0x7fff88942cb8` being the NSData address as per lldb.

Which files should I make the changes in, to get [`bookmarkDataWithContentsOfURL:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1408344-bookmarkdatawithcontentsofurl?language=objc) and [`URLByResolvingBookmarkData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1572035-urlbyresolvingbookmarkdata?language=objc) to work?

```c
void *pathclass::resolveAliasFromURL(const char *filepath) const
{
  NSError *error = nil;
  NSString *filepathh = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:filepath];
  NSData *bookmarkk = [NSData bookmarkDataWithContentsOfURL:filepathh]; /*problematic line*/


  BOOL isstale = NO;
  NSURL *actual = [NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:bookmarkk bookmarkDataIsStale:isstale error:error];/*another problematic line, but build fails already*/
  NSString *urlString = [actual absoluteString];
  NSLog(@"%@",urlString);
}
```

If there are any other faults, please point out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `bookmarkDataWithContentsOfURL:` is wrong in a few ways:

The signature looks like this:

```
+ (NSData *)bookmarkDataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)bookmarkFileURL error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error;
```

First, the first parameter is of type `NSURL*`, *not* `NSString*`. Next, you miss off the error parameter completely (despite defining a variable for it). Lastly, the method is a class method on `NSURL` *not* `NSData` (`NSData*` is the return type).

So, first, make your file path into an `NSURL*`:

```
NSURL* bookmarkUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:filepathh];
```

Then, call the function using the proper arguments:

```
NSData *bookmarkk = [NSURL bookmarkDataWithContentsOfURL:bookmarkUrl error:&error];
```

You should check the returned value against `nil` - if it's `nil`, then an error occurred, and the error information will be contained inside `error`.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1408344-bookmarkdatawithcontentsofurl?language=objc) is quite helpful.

Your call to `URLByResolvingBookmarkData:options:relativeToURL:bookmarkDataIsStale:error:` has similar problems: you are missing several parameters, the first parameter should be `NSURL`, etc. Again, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1572035-urlbyresolvingbookmarkdata?language=objc) should help.

Comment: **1** I thought that the parameters could be removed to narrow down the cause. **2** Also, what would be the return type in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1572035-urlbyresolvingbookmarkdata?language=objc case ? what is instancetype? **3** Also, this fixed a lot of my misconceptions about how the documentations presents something :) **4** I'll edit the title to remove the hints of XY problem.

Comment: 1. No, all parameters must be passed 2. `NSURL*` - `instancetype` means it will return an instance of the class containing this function